# Flag not set on last RadioButton

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

My application uses `onActivityResult` to get an address, generate a `RadioButton` with that address, and set a flag on the last `radioButton`. On first launch it works. My problem is that after closing the activity and repeating the operation to add an address, no flag is set on the last `radioButton`. I tried to fix this by calling `clearCheck()` method while clicking `navigationIcon` in `Toolbar`, but it didn't work

Adding an address and setting a flag

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (data == null) {
        return
    }
    val radioButton = RadioButton(this)
    radioButton.text = data.getStringExtra("ADDRESS")

    radioGroupAddress.apply {
        addView(radioButton)
        //Ставлю флаг на последний выбранный адрес
        check(radioGroupAddress.childCount)
    }
}
```

**UPD**

My Activity

```
@Inject
@InjectPresenter
lateinit var presenter: SupermarketOrderPresenter

@ProvidePresenter
fun providePresenter() = presenter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    App.appComponent
            .supermarketOrderInfo()
            .build()
            .inject(this)

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_supermarket)
    init()
}

private fun init() {
    initToolbar()
    initClickListeners()
}

private fun initToolbar(){
    //Инициализация тулбара
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
    //Получение тайтла для дальнейших манипуляций
    val titleToolbar = toolbar.getChildAt(0) as TextView
    //Установка тайтла для тулбара
    titleToolbar.text = getString(R.string.total_price_toolbar_order,
            intent.getStringExtra("TOTAL_PRICE"))
    //Установка шрифта для тулбара
    titleToolbar.typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.sf_pro_display_bold)
    //Клик на иконку "назад"
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
        radioGroupAddress.clearCheck()
        onBackPressed()
    }
}

private fun initClickListeners(){
    buttonAddAddress.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, SupermarketMapActivity::class.java)
        startActivityForResult(intent, 2)
    }

    imageButtonInfoDelivery.setOnClickListener {
        showDialogInfoDelivery()
    }
    buttonPay.setOnClickListener {
        when {
            radioGroupAddress.childCount == 0 -> {
                startActivityForResult(Intent(this, SupermarketMapActivity::class.java), 2)
            }
            editTextName.text.isNullOrEmpty() || maskedEditTextPhone.text!!.length < 18 -> {
                toast("Имя и телефон должны быть заполнены")
            }
            else -> startActivity(Intent(this, OrderSuccessSupermarketActivity::class.java))
        }
    }
}

private fun showDialogInfoDelivery() {
    val dialog = Dialog(this)
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_info_delivery)

    val buttonOk = dialog.findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonDialogInfo)
    buttonOk.setOnClickListener {
        dialog.dismiss()
    }
    dialog.show()
}

//Получаю выбранный на карте адрес
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (data == null) {
        return
    }
    val radioButton = RadioButton(this)
    radioButton.text = data.getStringExtra("ADDRESS")

    radioGroupAddress.apply {
        addView(radioButton)
        //Ставлю флаг на последний выбранный адрес
        check(radioGroupAddress.childCount)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[check](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup#check(int)) method is taking `int id` param, not position of `View`. after `addView` just use `radioButton.setChecked(true)`/`radioButton.checked = true` and `radioGroupAddress` should automatically un-check all others `RadioButton`s (assuming it is a `RadioGroup`)